# html_attr doesn't the 'href' attr

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

First of all I'm really beginner with web-scraping.

So work on [this](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/forum/41-e01-winter-is-coming/) wesite. I try to get the links to the next webpages with discussion about the espisode. With the SelectorGadget I managed to get only the part of the html with the frame with the topics

```
html.s1e01 <- html("http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/forum/41-e01-winter-is-coming/")

html.s1e01.page <- html_nodes(html.s1e01, ".ipsBox")
```

Now I want to get all links to the topics, so I tried

```
html_attr(html.s1e01.page, "href")
```

but I get `NA`. I saw similar examples on the Internet and it should work. Any suggestion why it does not?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what part of the website you want to scrap. If it is the 12 forum categories try `.expandable+ .expandable .topic_title span` instead of `.ipsBox` that you use.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I want. But changing `.ipsBox` to `.expandable+ .expandable .topic_title span` doesn't help. `html_attr(html.s1e01.page2, "href")` where `html.s1e01.page2 <- html_nodes(html.s1e01, ".expandable+ .expandable .topic_title span")` gives me vector of 12 `NA`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html.s1e01.page <- html_nodes(html.s1e01, ".ipsBox .topic_title")
html.s1e01.topics <- html.s1e01.page %>%  html_attr("href")
html.s1e01.topics

##  [1] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49408-poll-how-would-you-rate-episode-101/"                        
##  [2] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/109202-death-of-john-aryn-season-4-episode-5-spoilers/"            
##  [3] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49310-book-spoilers-episode-101-take-3/"                           
##  [4] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/90902-sir-john-standingjonarryn/"                                  
##  [5] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/106105-did-anyone-notice-the-color-of-the-feather-in-lyannas-tomb/"
##  [6] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49116-book-tv-spoilers-what-was-left-out-and-what-was-left-in/"    
##  [7] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49070-no-spoilers-ep101-discussion/"                               
##  [8] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49159-book-spoilers-the-book-was-better/"                          
##  [9] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/57614-runes-in-agot-spoilers-i-suppose/"                           
## [10] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49151-book-spoilers-ep101-discussion-mark-ii/"                     
## [11] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49161-booktv-spoilers-dany-drogo/"                                 
## [12] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49071-book-spoilers-ep101-discussion/"                             
## [13] "http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49100-no-spoilers-pre-airing-discussion/"
```